# Jquery mobile doesn't follow a link comming from another JQM page

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-map

I'm using the jquery-ui-map plugin and my test page (test.html) loads a Google Map correctly when I click the button. This SAME test.html don't work if a load it from another jquery mobile page. What I'm doing bad or what I'm missing? Next the significant code:

Javascript in the header (like in the example for the basic map):

```
var mobileDemo = { 'center': '57.7973333,12.0502107', 'zoom': 10 };
$('#basic_map').live('pageinit', function() {
  demo.add('basic_map', function() {
    $('#map_canvas').gmap({
      'center': mobileDemo.center, 
      'zoom': mobileDemo.zoom,
      'disableDefaultUI':true,
      'callback': function() {
    var self = this;
    self.addMarker({'position': this.get('map').getCenter() }).click(function() {
      self.openInfoWindow({ 'content': 'Hello World!' }, this);
      });
    }});
  }).load('basic_map');
});

$('#basic_map').live('pageshow', function() {
  demo.add('basic_map', function() { $('#map_canvas').gmap('refresh'); }).load('basic_map');
});
```

And the html (sorry, I can't post the HTML code because it's interpretatded, but the link is below):

http://www.medlifesolutions.com.mx/locations/mobile/test.html

As I said, this works perfect if I write test.html in the browser directly but if comes from another page:

http://www.medlifesolutions.com.mx/locations/mobile/main.php

it simply ignores a "click" or touching the button to show the map. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see in your code is the use of `live`. It is recommended to replace `live` with `on`.